Why make acronyms for the plagues?
In the Haggada, Rabbi Yehudah makes acronyms for the 10 plagues.
What was the purpose of making these acronyms?

Answering this off the cuff but either maybe it’s to show that each group has something in common (what that is you can figure out on your own). But I just heard from my rabbi this year that the gematriya of the acronyms is like five hundred something (I don’t have the exact numbers on hand), and the number of miracles that happened to us that is described in the section of the Haggadah immediately following the acronym adds up to the same number (it’s off by one but apparently you can overlook this in gematriya) when adding all three opinions

Good question. A lot of Haggados give different answers, finding patterns in the groupings. See esp. the Maharal.

https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42759&st=&pgnum=474
